# Why 'which' and not 'who'

Tags: relative-pronouns

As a choir singer I studied Arvo Pärt's composition "Which was the Son of...", text exracted from the Bible (Luke 3,23-38). It's simply Christ's genealogy. I was surprised that the relative pronoun used was 'which' and not 'who'. I suppose it is an ancient usage, and would not be correct in modern English

Thanks for an explanation!

Comment: *There were two of them. Which [of them] was the Son of …* Used in that context and sense, it seems less natural to say *who [of them] was the Son of  …*

Answer (score 2):

From the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com) (requires subscription)

> Which...
>   **I 2 b.**  Also (Old English and occasionally later) = Who. Obsolete except as a dialect or humorous substitute for what.

Comment: As a schoolkid in London in the 1950s I recited the Lord's Prayer starting "Our father, which art in  heaven..." which is in the King James Bible (Matthew Chapter 6 verses 9 to 13). Nobody wondered about it. Modern versions use 'who'. My Catholic wife was taught 'who' in the 1950s.

Comment: Thanks for the quote and the reference to King James Bible, which (!) I don't know as I'm Belgian

Comment: @MichaelHarvey ... the best-known musical setting by Albert Hay Malotte (1935) uses "Our Father which art in heaven..."

Answer (score 1):

In [King James Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%203%3A23-38&version=KJV) it's indeed "**which was**", but in [its 21st century edition](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%203%3A23-38&version=KJ21) it's "**who was**", so you are correct in saying that it is an ancient usage, and would not be correct in modern English.

However, there is one instance when you can refer to a person using "which": if it's followed by a noun.

> You decide **which doctor** is right for you.

[source](https://www.tk.de/en/i-am-tk/free-choice-doctor-2052946)

Comment: Thanks for your remark, but in this case it is not a relative pronoun, you could say 'any' or 'the best'